# Como o corpo de um envelope soap deve ser construido para um request?

Tags: web-service

Procurei por alguns tutoriais e até este ponto entendi que...

o Header contem os dados de autenticação do evelope, entretanto não sei com relação ao corpo... se as tags do corpo devem ter o mesmo nome das propriedades retornadas no WSDL.

Algum material esclarecedor?

O que necessariamente devo preencher no envelope de requisição?